# Ошибка Error:"unauthorized_client", Description:"Unauthorized client or scope in request.", Uri:""

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, google-api

Разрабатываю сайт, который должен работать с файлами из google drive. Все работало пока гугл не запретил использовать oauth 1.0. При переходе на новую версию написал такой код.

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2("pathToFile.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
var userAccountEmail = "************@gmail.com";
var serviceAccountEmail = "*****-******@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
    {
        Scopes = new[] { "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/" },
        User = userAccountEmail
    }.FromCertificate(certificate));
bool success = credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

На последней строке появляется ошибка:

> Исключение типа "System.AggregateException" возникло в mscorlib.dll, но не было обработано в коде пользователя"
>
> Error: "unauthorized_client", Description: "Unauthorized client or scope in request.", Uri:"

Пожалуйста, помогите кто знает в чем дело. Перерыл весь нет, ничего не помогло.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: к сожалению использование предложенного варианта проблему не решает. После манипуляции с кодом пришел к выводу что проблема с "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/". Если строку User = userAccountEmail удалить - то контактов не получаю. Я пробовал с drive ом работать. там все ок. но как только добавляется "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/" в scope  - перестает работать

Comment: @Владимир, а второй предложенный read-only вариант `scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly"` не пробовал? Ну или возможно сервисному аккаунту не расшарены контакты?

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря, совсем не разбираюсь в данном вопросе - просто погуглил ["Unauthorized client or scope in request"](https://www.google.ru/search?q=Unauthorized+client+or+scope+in+request&oq=Unauthorized+client+or+scope+in+request&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2.263j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8), и понеслось :)

*Решение*: убрать строку `User = userAccountEmail`.
*Почему*: [отсюда [eng]](http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-authentication-with-c/#Google_CalendarAPI_Service_Account_Authentication) (там примеры кода есть, если что):

> The two types of Authentication you can use are:
>
> - Open Authentication or  OAuth2 – Which is designed to allow you to 
>     access other peoples data. 
>     For example: a user installs your
>     application that will allow them to view there Google Calendar Data,
>     before your application can view there data the user will be asked to 
>     authenticate your application giving your application permission to
>     access their data.
> - Service Account Authentication – Which is designed to allow you to 
>     access your own data. For example: you would    like to display a
>     Calendar for your website. For this there is no    reason to ask
>     permission because you already own this data.

Вольный перевод следующий. 
Для доступа *к инфе чужих аккаунтов*, используется первый метод, в котором отсутствует понятие Service Account. Ты посылаешь запрос, и у человека всплывает окно "Приложение запрашивает доступ", где он может выбрать "Разрешить" или "Запретить". 
Код из приведенного источника.

```
// From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com
string clientId = "";
string clientSecret = "";

string userName = ""; //  A string used to identify a user.
string[] scopes = new string[] {
    CalendarService.Scope.Calendar, // Manage your calendars
    CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly // View your Calendars
};

// here is where we Request the user to give us access, 
// or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    new ClientSecrets {
        ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret
    }, 
    scopes, userName, CancellationToken.None, 
    new FileDataStore("Daimto.GoogleCalendar.Auth.Store")
).Result;
```

Для доступа *к своей инфе*, ты создал Service Account (судя по примеру в вопросе) и расшариваешь ему инфу со своих аккаунтов. В коде тогда обращаешься только к Service Account, минуя упоминание о своем личном аккаунте (-ах). То есть удаляешь строку с передачей свойства `User` у `ServiceAccountCredential`. 
Код из приведенного источника.

```
string[] scopes = new string[] {
    CalendarService.Scope.Calendar, // Manage your calendars
    CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly, // View your Calendars
    "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/", // read/write contacts
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly", // read contacts
 };

var certificate = new X509Certificate2(
    keyFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable
);

ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail) {
        Scopes = scopes
    }
    .FromCertificate(certificate)
);
```

***В итоге*** наткнулся на `developers.google.com` на сравнение [способов авторизации](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) на базе OAuth 2.0. В оглавлении слева можно найти много полезного по ссылкам в части "OAuth 2.0 Authorization", где уже подробно описаны все эти способы.

Надеюсь, я правильно понял и передал смысл найденной мной инфы, и что решение поможет.